# J/Link doesn't work with Java 8?

Tags: java

I have some code that successfully uses J/Link (well... until today when something I was doing something with it that crashed the JVM, so), and I recently tried running it under Java 8.

I then get a stack trace:

```
Fatal error: cannot find the required native library named JLinkNativeLibrary.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.wolfram.jlink.NativeLink.MLOpenString(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at com.wolfram.jlink.NativeLink.MLOpenString(Native Method)
    at com.wolfram.jlink.NativeLink.<init>(NativeLink.java:117)
    at com.wolfram.jlink.MathLinkFactory.createMathLink0(MathLinkFactory.java:281)
    at com.wolfram.jlink.MathLinkFactory.createMathLink(MathLinkFactory.java:194)
    at com.wolfram.jlink.MathLinkFactory.createKernelLink0(MathLinkFactory.java:171)
    at com.wolfram.jlink.MathLinkFactory.createKernelLink(MathLinkFactory.java:65)
```

> Do I need to change something to run under Java 8? Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: What OS is this running on?  If windows, the error message suggests that JLinkNativeLibrary is not on the OS Path.

Comment: @Ymareth, this is on OS X. When using Java 7 it successfully finds the library based on its relative path from JLink.jar. Under Java 8 apparently not.

Comment: Can you try (have you tried already) with the library explicitly on the path?